# Creating a Shared Entity Framework Connection

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have an existing DbConnection (not from Entity Framework).  I want to create a DbContext that shares the existing connection (so that my database operations are part of the same transaction).  I can create a DbContext with the existing (open) connection, but when I try and do a simple query on the database via EF, it fails because the model hasn't been loaded into the new DbContext.  How can I do this?  I'm using Entity Framework 6.1, database first.

To create the DbContext with the shared connection, I simply call:

```
new DbContext(connection, false);
```

Where connection is an existing, open DbConnection, created using:

```
IDatabaseDriver.GetConnection(settings);
```

The exception is: System.InvalidOperationException.

The message is: The entity type XXX is not part of the model for the current context.

I believe I need to use the constructor DbContext(existingConnection, model, contextOwnsConnection).  Is this correct?  If so, how can I get a DbCompiledModel in a database-first setup?

Comment: Please show relevant code and the actual error.

Comment: Show the code where you share the connection. I bet you don't initialize the model there.

Comment: You can't use a `DbContext` like that. You must create a derived class with mappings to your database.